# How to export data in datagridview into text file And Import it VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How to export data in datagridview into text file And Import it VB.net
i have tried to solve this problem:

```
    Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter("G:\Visual Studio 2010\b.txt")
        For row As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

            For col As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1

                IO.File.WriteAllText("G:\Visual Studio 2010\C.txt", DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(col).Value.ToString & ",")
            Next
        Next
    End Using
```

This is last Code.i wrote other codes.but all fail.i have tried export data to xml and import. [Fail]
Please write The correct code + solve import problem

Comment: If you don't need a specific format, use a `DataTable` to store the data. You can call `WriteXml` to write it to an XML file and then `ReadXml` to read the file back into a `DataTable`. Just bind your `DataTable` to your grid and you're done. It's basically three lines of code for the lot.

Comment: You create a StreamWriter but you never use it.

The docs on File.WriteAllText https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext say "Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten." This is not at all what you want to do

Comment: How did you fill the DataGridView to begin with?

Comment: I forget i put it in a comment.because i used it before

Comment: @Mary I make user fill it. i make a button when user click on it, make a columns. i want to save it and load it only

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code that I use. It is Tab delimited but you can change it to how you want.

#Region "*** File Load and Save (DataGridView)***"

```
Sub ReadTSV()
    Dim TextLine As String
    Dim SplitLine() As String

    If System.IO.File.Exists(DataPath & "\Tracker.tsv") = True Then
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(DataPath & "\Tracker.tsv", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ControlChars.Tab)
            Me.dgvTracker.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
        Loop
        objReader.Close()
    Else
        'MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub WriteDataGridViewTSV()
    'Build the TSV file data as a Tab separated string.

    Dim tsv As String = String.Empty

    'Adding the Rows
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvTracker.Rows
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            tsv = tsv & CType(cell.Value, String) & ControlChars.Tab 'Add the Data rows
        Next

        'trim the last Tab and Add new line
        tsv = tsv.TrimEnd(ControlChars.Tab) & vbCrLf

    Next

    If tsv.Length > 4 Then  'Remove the extra lines at the end of the tsv file
        tsv = tsv.Substring(0, tsv.Length - 4)
    Else
        tsv = ""            'Delete extra row if empty
    End If

    File.WriteAllText(DataPath & "\Tracker.tsv", tsv)

End Sub
```

Comment: i want to save columns ,too

Answer (score 0):

This code shows an example of the comment by jmcilhinney.

In the Form.Load I check it the xml and xsd files exist. It they do then they are read and fill the `DataTable` with the schema and data. If they do not exist them a new `DataTable` is created. Finally the `DataTable` is bound to the `DataGridView`.

Any data that the user adds or changes in the `DataGridView` is recorded in the `DataTable`. Saving the data and schema is equally simple. Just extract the `DataTable` from the grid and write the schema and data.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt As DataTable
    If File.Exists("test.xml") AndAlso File.Exists("test.xsd") Then
        dt = New DataTable
        dt.ReadXmlSchema("test.xsd")
        dt.ReadXml("test.xml")
        MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString)
    Else
        dt = CreateDataTable()
    End If
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Function CreateDataTable() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable("MyDataTable")
    dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("LastName", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Rank", GetType(Integer))
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Pretend this is the Save button
    Dim dt = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
    dt.WriteXmlSchema("test.xsd")
    dt.WriteXml("test.xml")
End Sub
```